# Rendering component in component Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components

I am building a system that can generate HTML from JSON.

The following JSON

```
"type": "span",
"content": [
  {
    "type": "span",
    "content": [
      {
        "type": "div",
        "content": []
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Should generate The following html

```
<span>
 <span>
  <div></div>
 </span>
</span>
```

I have made this to convert the JSON

```
export default {
  name: 'HTMLElement',
  props: {
      data: {
          type: Array,
          default: []
      }
  },
  render(createElement) {
      return createElement(
          this.data.type,
          createElement(
              HTMLElement,
              {
                  props: {
                      data: this.data.content
                  }
              }
          )
      );
  }
}
```

The propertie data is the JSON only than parsed to a Object

When I am running this code I get the following error

```
Failed to construct 'HTMLElement': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function.
```

Has anyone any idea of a better solution or a fix to this situation ?

Thank you in advance,

Jeroen

Comment: What if you changed `HTMLElement,` to `new HTMLElement,`

Comment: You should quote `HTMLElement`, also, arrays don;t have the `type` & `content`  properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be in need of a recursive function. See the `buildElement` method below. It is used in the `render()` and works as you describe:

```js
Vue.component('html-element', {
  name: 'HTMLElement',
  props: {
    data: {
      type: Object,
      default: {type: 'div'}
    }
  },
  render(createElement) {
    return this.buildElement(createElement, this.data)
  },
  methods: {
    buildElement(createElementFunction, data) {
      return createElementFunction(
        data.type, (data.content || []).map(c => this.buildElement(createElementFunction, c))
      );
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    elementData: {
      "type": "span",
      "content": [{
        "type": "span",
        "content": [{
          "type": "div",
          "content": []
        }]
      }]
    }
  }
})
```

```css
span { display: inline-block; border: 1px solid red; width: 50px }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<span>
 <span>
  <div></div>
 </span>
</span>

<hr>

<div id="app">
  <html-element :data="elementData"></html-element>
</div>
```